# Counter variable: how does it work?

Tags: c++

I was writing a piece of software that allows to the user to compute the average of ten integer numbers. This is the code:

```
// Algorithm for computing the average of the grades of a class with the controlled iteration of a counter

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int total,          // sum of all grades
        gradeCounter,   // n° of inputted grades
        grade,          // a single vote
        average;        // average of grades

        // initialization phase
        total = 0;              //sets the total to zero
        gradeCounter = 1;       //prepares the counter

    // elaboration phase
    while ( gradeCounter <= 10 ) { // 10 times cycle    
        cout << "Enter grade: "; // input prompt
        cin >> grade;            // input grade
        total = total + grade;   // adds the grade to the total
        gradeCounter = gradeCounter + 1; // increases the counter
    }

    // end phase
    average = total / gradeCounter;
    cout << "The class average is " << average << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Now, I was thinking that writing `average = total / gradeCounter;` would work, since the last variable stored in `gradeCounter` is 10; but the result given by `average = total / 10;` is the real average. I don't get why there's this discrepancy.
Can somebody explain this to me?

Comment: `gradeCounter` will be `11` when the program reaches the average calculation, otherwise it would still be in the loop. And you might consider using `float` or `double` to store the resulting average.

Comment: `total` and `gradeCounter` are both integers. Research **integer division**

Comment: You may get used to zero based ranges [included, excluded) and use `for(gradeCounter = 0; gradeCounter < 10; ++gradeCounter)`

Comment: Thanks everybody for the explanations!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually what is happening is that after each run of your while loop, the value of `gradeCounter` is 1 more than the number of times the loop has been run(because you have initialized `gradeCounter` to 1 before start of the loop). You can do any 1 of the following to fix this.

1)

```
average = total / (gradeCounter-1);
```

2)

```
gradeCounter = 0;
while ( gradeCounter < 10 ) {
    cout << "Enter grade: ";
    cin >> grade;
    total = total + grade; 
    gradeCounter = gradeCounter + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
while ( gradeCounter <= 10 ) { //10 times cycle 
    cout << "Enter grade: "; //input prompt
    cin >> grade;            //input grade
    total = total + grade;   //adds the grade to the total
    gradeCounter = gradeCounter + 1; //increases the counter
}
```

In this piece of code, when `gradeCounter` is `10`, the `while` loop runs once more, incrementing `gradeCounter` to `11`. So later, you're really dividing by 11 rather than 10.

Answer (score 1):

```
while ( gradeCounter <= 10 )
```

This condition evaluates to false when, in your case, `gradeCounter` is incremented to 11.
(11 is not less or equal to 10)

So your counter is eleven, not ten after your loop.

Answer (score 1):

`while ( gradeCounter <= 10 ) { //10 times cycle`
`gradeCounter = gradeCounter + 1;`

Grade counter will be 11 after the loop ends (last iteration it gets set to 11, then <= 10 is not true and it exits. So you'd be doing a divide by 11 instead of 10.

Answer (score 0):

You should draw a flowchart for this.  If `gradeCounter <= 10`, you go into the loop, and only when `gradeCounter >= 11` do you proceed with `average = total/gradeCounter`

That's why you get a result divided by 11 instead of 10.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation!

Comment: You also need to set the counter to zero so the number of items read is the same as the counter

Comment: @EdHeal: He asked for an explanation, and no, one doesn't need to set the counter to zero in order to fix the calculation, because one doesn't need the number of items read to be equal to the counter.  `average = total / (gradeCounter-1);` would also be a valid fix, as is `average = total / 10;` as already mentioned in the question.

Comment: Please correct the final calculation so that the average is correct whatever method you chose